Pymol not starting after downloading using linux terminal command
Hello everyone Iam currently using Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I am downloading from linux terminal using "sudo apt-get install pymol" and successfully installing pymol.
> sudo apt-get install pymol
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
pymol is already the newest version (2.5.0+dfsg-1build6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

However, when I am trying to run the software using terminal command pymol it is showing the following error.
$ pymol
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "<frozen runpy>", line 189,> in _run_module_as_main   
File "<frozen runpy>", line 112, in> _get_module_details  
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymol/__init__.py", line 81, in> <module>>    
 from imp import find_module ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'


Please edit your question and add information which version of Ubuntu you are using.

There is not such version of Ubuntu as this Debian Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp' error message is reproducible on my Ubuntu 24.04.

If the error is reproducible, a bug report of the package to be opened on Launchpad may make sense.

It seems that imp was removed from Python3.12 - see for example What’s New In Python 3.12: imp - there's a python3-zombie-imp package in universe that might provide a workaround?

@steeldriver your comment looks like a possible answer to me.

Reproducible here.

I had the same issue, and the following workaround fixed it for me:
sudo apt install python3-zombie-imp

Thanks to the comment of @steeldriver for this tip!

It seems that imp was removed from Python3.12 - see for example What’s
New In Python 3.12: imp - there's a python3-zombie-imp package in
universe that might provide a workaround?


Ref.
In Python 3.12 there is no module called imp. Instead of use importlib as:
from importlib import import_module

Additional info provided by the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html#imp
